# Convert an old javascript package to export a typescript module

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I got this old javascript package i need to use in a modern typescript application.

```
!(function (t, e) {
..
  (window.TradingView = window.xx || {}), (window.xx.version = r), (t.version = r), (t.widget = s), Object.defineProperty(t, "__esModule", { value: !0 });
});
```

Typescript complains it's no module exported from this file.

Is there any easy way I can make an export of this so it works in typescript?

Comment: Do you have the source code of the package as well? What you posted is the transpiled and minified version.

Comment: Are you trying to convert or to use the JS file?

Comment: @Bergi I only have the transpiled minified version. It's a propiatory software so I cant share it.

Comment: Then you will need to manually strip off the IIFE (although the code you posted doesn't look quite right) and `export` the properties of that `t` object.

Answer (score 0):

If you know, what the package exports, probably the easiest way would be to write a file with declarations. You create `TradingView.d.ts` somewhere and write declarations for the class that is exported:

```
declare class TradingView {\
  field1: bool

  method1(arg1: number): void
  method2(arg2: string): Map
}
```

Then you need to include this file either with triple-slash directive

```
/// <reference path="./path/to/TradingView.d.ts" />
```

Or in `tsconfig`:

```
"include": ["...", "./path/to/TradingView.d.ts"]
```